# I tried using google analytics in My django app and it didn't work

Tags: python, django, google-analytics

I just recently signed up for google analytics and added it to the base template of my Django blogging app. I thought that it would register all the pages that use the base.html, similar to how Disqus commenting app  works, Where you place it on the details page and it works for all of the posts. But when I sign in to google analytics and view whose on my site. It only registers the home page. If I go to other pages it says no one is on my site. Then I tried adding

```
{% block analytics %}
{% endblock analytics %}
```

on the home page and

```
{% block analytics %}
  analytics code here
{% endblock analytics %}
```

on all the other pages but then not even the home page registered. How Do I make it work with my django app? django-google-analytics doesnt work with the version of python I'm using.

Comment: Are all of your other templates extending `base.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put this snippet:

```
{% block analytics %}
  analytics code here
{% endblock analytics %}
```

In your base.html so every page will have the tracking code.
In case you need to override that you can do it in specific pages overidding the `analytics` block.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Additionally, if you override the analytics block on a page that's extending `base.html`, it will replace the analytics code altogether, which might be your issue.

Comment: @Marco I tried that already and it didn't work. i'm going to try it again?

Comment: @CurtisOlson How do I fix the issue?

Comment: @user3650429 what you mean "it didn't work"? What you did? Can you give a full example of the final page?

Comment: @marco I did what you suggested. But I don't understand what you mean when you say override

Comment: @user3650429 
In regards to your override question:
If you put  the snippet in base.html it will add "analytics code here" on every one of your pages. However if you were to add {% block analytics %}something new{% endblock analytics %} to one of your pages extending base.html, then "something new" would effectively override "analytics code here"